# Translate Data...Exampe: johnsmith@example.com to John Smith in PHP? Or Java?

Tags: javascript, php, html

For Example:

I have an HTML dropdown email list of people's emails and rather than listing emails  in the drop down I want to show predefined names.

The emails are used in a script that runs on the next page in PHP to send an email to the option selected on the dropdown once the form is submitted so they are vital as a value to the form.

Is this possible? I can't seem to find anything on this because I don't know what to call it. I assume it would be some sort of data "translation" Like translating example@gmail.com to John Smith.

Comment: Why not just use a `<select>`? You can set the value as the email address and the display text as the person's name for each option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<option>` tag allows you to do that.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_option.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can have in a dropdown menu a label and a value for each entry. The label is the name and the value the e-mail.

Isn't it ?

Comment: It's inline with PHP, even with a value set it still defaults to whats between the option tags.

Comment: Nevermind. I'm an idiot... I realized that the value tag is what actually goes to the server...

Answer (score 0):

incase if someone looking for something like this.

```
    <select id="emails">
      <option value="john@1235.com">name</option>
      <option value="jack@1234.com">name</option>
      <option value="tom@1234.com">name</option>
   </select>
```

javascript to get the value attribute and pick the first part of the email address and display it as name in the option tag

```
 $('#emails option').each(function() {
    var opname = $(this).attr('value');
    var name = opname.split('@')[0];
    $(this).html(name);});
```